# How to create a subscription pallet?

Tags: pallet, polkadot, frame, blockchain

As the title is descriptive, I would like to create a subscription pallet. A user needs to subscribe first and the receiver can receive the payment every month.
Any idea how to design this pallet?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in various ways. Depending on the duration also aspects like building a reserve can be relevant. E.g. one time payment is simple but recurring payments, maybe collected in a map with blocktime to execute the subscription payment `on_finalize`, could also raise questions, when the subscriber has insufficient funds. Otoh, if they would pay e.g. one year in advance you could build a reserve in the subscriber account or transfer to the service provider account and release through something like a vesting scheduler.

hth

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there are couple ways to do it. Maybe you can clarify your requirement exactly, so we can cut off many ways that is inappropriate.